# Run second statement if first statement is successfully executed

Tags: php

I have a PHP script which I am using to send data to my database. If the SQL statement is successfully executed I want to send an UPDATE statement that looks like:

```
UPDATE accounts SET status='1' WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] ."'
```

Is it possible to run a second statement if the first statement is succesfully executed? If yes, then how can I do that?

Here is the script I am using to send data to the database:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) 

$correct = true;

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'] ;
$_SESSION['user_id'];
$status = $_POST['status'] ;

if($correct){
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');

$query = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, user_id, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($firstname, $lastname, $_SESSION['user_id'], $status));

$id = $db->lastInsertId();
            header('Location: ../success.php?id='.$id);
}else{
            header('Location: ../error.php');
}
?>
```

If the both sql statements are successfully executed I want to send the user to the page `../success.php?id='.$id`

**Edit 1:**

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, user_id, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" ;
$stmt = $db->prepare($query1);
$stmt->execute(array($firstname, $lastname, $_SESSION['user_id'], $status));


// the below code will execute if your insertion is successful
$query2 = "UPDATE accounts SET status='1' WHERE user_id='" . $_SESSION['user_id'] ."'" ;

// set the header location to go to another page


$id = $db->lastInsertId();
            header('Location: ../success.php?id='.$id);
}else{
            header('Location: ../error.php');
}
```

Comment: do u tried to execute the update query ?

Comment: Yes, the update query is working

Comment: i can't see the the  $query2->execute()   here.

Comment: I dont get it. Do i need to change  `$query = "UPDATE ....."` to `$query2->execute() = "UPDATE ....."`?

Comment: @HackerBoy I saw your edit.  It is still not working

Comment: You do not seem to use our answers in your edited code. Both answers would definitely fix your issue if you would actually try them.

Comment: @HackerBoy why did you go and change the OP's code? https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44341476/3 did they instruct you to do so?

Comment: @John see the above comment ^ --- and `$_SESSION['user_id'];` doesn't do anything.  Do all POST/GET/SESSION arrays contain value? You also didn't execute the UPDATE. You should also use full proper bracing.

Comment: @John no idea why you let them edit your question like that. Anyway, I'll let you guys sort this out.

Comment: i added $query1  and $query2 just  for clarity

Answer (score 0):

`$stml->execute()` returns true on success. so, u can check

```
   if($correct){
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');

        $query = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, user_id, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $exec = $stmt->execute(array($firstname, $lastname, $_SESSION['user_id'], $status));

        if($exec){
            ....do update query
            // set the header location to go to another page
        }
    }
```

or simply you can do this

```
   if($correct){
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'root', '');

        $query = "INSERT INTO users(firstname, lastname, user_id, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $exec = $stmt->execute(array($firstname, $lastname, $_SESSION['user_id'], $status)) or die();

        // the below code will execute if your insertion is successful
        ....do update query
        // set the header location to go to another page
    }
```

Comment: Have my upvote. Your answer would actually work. Don't understand why this is downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

You can. Use the return value of `$statement->execute();`

```
if ($statement->execute()) {
    // next statement
}
```

<sup>Read more about this in the [documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).</sup>

## Error handling

In addition to the example above you can check the error code. Something is bound to go wrong at a certain point so you're going to need to perform some error handling. Check the error code and decide what to do accordingly.

A small example:

```
if ($statement->errorCode() === "00000") {
    // everything went well!
} else {
    throw new Exception("Something went wrong!");
}
```

<sup>Read more about that in the [documentation](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorcode.php) as well.</sup>

Comment: I tried your code. The principal is the same. When I enter the SQL statement it is not working

Comment: Well if that's the case, please give us more details about WHAT is not working. Just saying it ain't working is not gonna help us help you.